# Runtime exception while running robolectric 3.0 unit tests in Android studio 1.2

Tags: android-studio, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am running android unit tests using Robolectric 3.0 and have run in to this runtime exception. All the tests pretty much gives the same exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: you should only be calling this from the main thread!
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:244)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: you should only be calling this from the main thread!
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.resetThreadLoopers(ShadowLooper.java:52)
    at org.robolectric.Shadows.reset(Shadows.java:1617)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.reset(Robolectric.java:22)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.resetStaticState(ParallelUniverse.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:233)
    ... 34 more
```

I have tried many suggested options such as adding *--rerun-tasks* to script parameters, uncheck the "Use in-process build" option in *Compiler -> Gradle settings* of Android Studio etc..but none of them have worked.

Here is a sample of my build.gradle dependency list:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:18.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:1.46'

    testCompile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.50'

    testCompile ('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3'){
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-maps:3.0'
}
```

Have spent many hours looking in to it but with no result. I highly appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: Why your shadows have version 3.0 and robolectric is 3.0-rc3? How do you run your test - through gradle?

Comment: Also wiremock is standalone web app and should not be mentioned at any kind of scope dependency

Comment: You also use quite old compat library, and why do you forcing update check?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thanks for your reply. Yes i am running through the unit tests through gradle. As for shadows version..my bad. I have corrected them all to use version 3.0. I have removed wiremock since i did not need it.  my app is behaving strange with latest support v7 libraries and hence have to use the older version for now until i upgrade the app. The problem still exists

Comment: Can you share you external build script or even put project somewhere public? Do you really use robolectric gradle plugin?